# Entity Framework, generics: how to work with multiple tables that derive from a common inherited type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

Suppose I have a `DbSet` like so:

```
DbSet<Teacher>
```

And a `Teacher` inherits from a `Person` (not part of the EF generated classes).

```
public partial class Teacher: Person
{
}
```

And I have a list of `DbSet`s like so

```
var tableList = new List<Type>() { typeof(DbSet<Teacher>), typeof(DbSet<Student>), ... };
```

Then I want to create a generic function that does the same thing for each of the tables in the list.

How do I do something like the following if I know that all the tables in the list can inherit from the same `Person` type:

```
foreach(var tableType in tableList)
{
    var table = (DbSet<Person>)Activator.CreateInstance(tableType);

    var existing = table.Where(x => x.Name == "whatever");

    if (!existing.Any())
    {
         table.Add(new Person{ Name = "Whatever" });
    }
...
```

The problem is that EF doesn't know which table in the database I want to talk to. How do I tell it that 'in this loop I want you to save the new person to the `Student` table, in this loop I want you to save to the `Teacher` table, etc?

I've tried initialising the table like so but neither are useful:

```
var table = (DbSet<dynamic>)Activator.CreateInstance(tableType);

var table = (DbSet<tableType>)Activator.CreateInstance(tableType);
```

Note: I know I could've made loads of separate very similar functions for each table type but I've made the above example simple to make the problem easier to understand, I'm not *actually* saving different types of people in a loop based on whether their name exists. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since there are so many generic methods involved, you would be better off writing your own generic method, then use reflection to call it.

```cs
public void ProcessGeneric<T> where T:Person, new()
{
    // Perhaps something like;
    var dbSet = db.Set<T>();
    if (!dbSet.Any(p => p.Name == ...))
        dbSet.Add(new T(){ ... });
}

public void Process(Type t)
    => this.GetType()
        .GetMethod(nameof(ProcessGeneric))
        .MakeGenericMethod(t)
        .Invoke(this, new object[] {});
```